# Playing an HD video in Android's WebView

Tags: android, video, webview

When I play HTML5 video in the web view of my application on a device with HD output, it is far much blurry when compared to same video played in Android's Default Browser.

I've already used the attributes `hardwareAccelerated="true"`, `setPluginState(PluginState.ON)`, `setPluginsEnabled(true)`, etc in my application/webwiew.

Is there any special settings for HD videos?